# Function - matrix with equal sum rows nad columns

Tags: r, function, matrix

I have to create a function that creates a "n" by "n" matrix with natural numbers and sum of columns and rows must be equal. 
Function `f(n, s)` should have 2 arguments:

- n - dimension
- s - sum

I have a partial solution to this problem:

```
n<-3
s<-20
m<-matrix(rep(0,n^2),n)

for (c in 1:n){
    for (r in 1:n){
        if (r==n) m[r,c]<-s-sum(m[1:r-1,c])
        else{
           m[r,c]<-round(runif(1,1,s-(n-1)-sum(m[1:r,c])))
           print (sum(m[1:r,c]))
        }
    }
}

m
```

Sum is only equal for column. I need help with improving my code. I'd be most grateful for your help!

Comment: Assuming s>n, (without which the problem is intractable) `diag(n)*(s-n)+1` does what you ask.

Comment: Miff's very short answer works if s > n, but the problem can be solved if s = n. You could do `if (n == s) { matrix(1, nrow=n, ncol=n) } else { diag(n)*(s-n)+1 }`. Or if you take zero to be a natural number, just `diag(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want some randomness in your construction, rather than just a diagonal matrix, one approach would be:

1. Initialise matrix with smallest possible values (I'm assuming natural numbers start at 1, others define them as starting at zero)
2. Identify rows and columns that are less than the desired sum
3. Select one of the entries in this subset and increment it
4. Carry on steps 2. and 3. until no more rows and columns are less than the desired sum.

You could implement this in R as:

```
n<-3
s<-20

d <- matrix(1, n, n) #or 0 if you prefer

while (sum(d)<s*n) {
  rows <- which(colSums(d)<s)
  cols <- which(rowSums(d)<s)
  r <- sample(rows,1)
  c <- sample(cols,1)
  d[r,c] <- d[r,c] + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.
Considering natural numbers starting from 1 and you need no zeros in your matrix and s>n.
This code will scan through matrix generating random numbers for the entire row (ith row) and entire column (ith column) in single iteration of i.
Try it for any value of n and s **condition (s>n)**

```
n<-3
s<-20
m<-matrix(0,nrow=n, ncol=n)
for(i in 1:n){
    for(k in i:n){
        if(k==i){       
            if(k==n){       #diagonal and last element of matrix
                m[i,k]<-s-sum(m[k, 1:k])
            }
            else{           #diagonal element
                m[i, k]<-round(runif(1,1, s-max(sum(m[k, 1:k]),sum(m[1:k, k]))-(n-k)))
            }
        }
        else{
            if(k==n){       
                m[k, i]<-s-sum(m[1:k, i]) #NOT diagonal but nth element. i.e row=n
                m[i, k]<-s-sum(m[i, 1:k]) #NOT diagonal but nth element. i.e col=n
            }
            else{           #any other element in matrix
                m[k, i]<-round(runif(1,1, s-max(sum(m[k, 1:i]),sum(m[1:k, i]))-(n-k)))  #i = col
                m[i, k]<-round(runif(1,1, s-max(sum(m[i, 1:k]),sum(m[1:i, k]))-(n-k)))  #i = row
            }
        }
    }
}
m
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very helpful! But it returns negative values, I had the same problem with my code; I didn't and still don't know how to involve the condition for natural numbers.